# How do I used angularjs translator conditionally for HTML label

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

How do I use angular translator for below condition?

```
<label class="control-label col-md-3">{{vm.showVat ?  Inclusive  :   Amount}} </label>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the translate filter in this way:

```
{{vm.showVat ? 'Inclusive' : 'Amount' | translate}}"
```

Where 'Inclusive' and 'Amount' are the keys for the translated values

Answer (score 0):

How calling a method that returns you translated text. You can put as much logic as you like in there and it is much easier to test than using angular.element

Comment: i tried by calling an method, it will be translate the string based on my condition but i am getting below exception.

[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Comment: To me that looks like you are going into an infinite loop. As a simpler  solution than a function how about using ng-if or ng-show/hide. You could add 2 label rows in one displaying Inclusive and the other displaying amount with them toggled by the if