# Angular translate filter in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to translate my project into another language. I used angular translate library and provided an external JSON file with the translations. It looks like this:

```
{
  "hello_world": "Hola Mundo"
}
```

When I'm using it with simple hardcoded strings it works just fine and I get my correct translations:

```
<p>{{ "hello_world" | translate }}</p>
```

But how to deal with the ternary operator in code like this?

```
<button> {{ conditionValue ? 'Show' : 'Hide' }} </button>
```

How to change those 'Show' and 'Hide' values into a translation filter with Angular Translate? I tried different ways but I got an invalid syntax errors.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I used angularjs translator conditionally for HTML label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781875/how-do-i-used-angularjs-translator-conditionally-for-html-label)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think if you wrap the `ternary operator` into `()`, it will work.

```
<button> {{ ( conditionValue ? 'Show' : 'Hide' ) | translate }} </button>
```

Answer (score 4):

you may try for this:

here i make username online and offline when you choose soanish, the user online status will change into spnish based on ternary condition.

https://plnkr.co/edit/o16dpI?p=preview

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/o16dpI?p=preview][1]

{{ ( userName ? 'Show' : 'Hide' ) | translate }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just come up with the solution!
For ternary operators we have to use 'translate' directive instead of filter. And it works just fine:

```
{
  "show_value": "Show",
  "hide_value": "Hide",
}

<button translate> {{ conditionValue ? "show_value" : "hide_value" }} </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your language JSON file

```
"CONFIGURATION": {
    "NEW_TEMPLATE": "New Template",
    "EDIT_TEMPLATE": "Edit Template"
}
```

CASE-I (With HTML tag)

```
<button> {{ ( variable === '5' ? 'CONFIGURATION.NEW_TEMPLATE' : 'CONFIGURATION.EDIT_TEMPLATE' ) | translate }} </button>
```

CASE-II (With some third party attribute)

```
<p-dialog header="{{(variable === '5' ? 'CONFIGURATION.NEW_TEMPLATE' : 'CONFIGURATION.EDIT_TEMPLATE') | translate}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If exist prefix

```
{{ ('massmedias.' + (ctrl.actionType === 'add' ? 'add' : 'rename')) | translate }}
```